# Customize Calendar Appointment Preview (popout) in Outlook 2013 with c#

Tags: calendar, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, ribbonx

Is there any way to customize (or replace) the box that displays details of a particular appoint as you scroll over it in the Calendar Explorer of Outlook 2013.

I am trying to display one of the additional custom properties (formatted) to give a visual queue of the status of an item without having to open it up in it's Inspector and navigate to the custom form region that provides the UI.

I have created form regions, and used RibbonXML at a very rudimentary level, but couldn't see a way to do this using either of those approaches.

Thanks in advance